# Orientation issue on android

Tags: android, orientation, oncreate

Currently I am working on audio streaming on android. All method I have written related to streaming and playing the audio is in the onCreate() method. The problem is when ever I change into portrait mode, all methods are called again. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When orientation is changed currently active Activity is destroyed and a new one is created.

Either you could prevent orientation change with `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` or move audio streaming code to a Service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `android:configChanges="orientation"` this on your Manifest to your activity. That will stop it from calling Oncreate again.